# D3.js filter existing html table

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coffeescript, html-table

So I have an html table that I created with d3 and I'm trying to filter down the results based on the text in an input box.

Right now I have:

```
    filterFunc:(toFilter,model)->
    for column in @columns
        if model.get(column)
            if model.get(column).indexOf(toFilter) != -1
                return true
    return false

renderTable:()=>
    @table =    d3.select("#search-results-area").append("table").attr("id",@tableId).attr("class","visualization-panel")
    @thead = @table.append("thead")
    @tbody = @table.append("tbody")
    @input = @table.append("input").attr("id",@inputId).on("keydown",(d)=>
        toFilter = $(@input[0][0]).val() 
        window.setTimeout((()=> 
            toFilter = $(@input[0][0]).val() 
            @rows.filter((d)=>
                    console.log "toFilter"
                    console.log toFilter
                    if @filterFunc(toFilter,d)
                        console.log d
                        return d 
                )

            console.log toFilter
            ),1000)

        )

    @columns = @json["Columns"]
    @initializeSortingFunctionManager(@columns)
    @thead.append("tr").selectAll("th").data(@columns).enter().append("th").text((col)-> return col).on("click",(d)=>@tbody.selectAll("tr").sort(@sortingFunctionManager[d]))
    @tbody.selectAll("tr").attr("class","spacing center-text")
    @renderTableBody()

renderTableBody:()=>
    @rows = @tbody.selectAll("tr").data(@collection.models).enter().append("tr")
    cells = @rows.selectAll("td").data((model)=>
        return @columns.map((column)=>
            return { column : column, val : model.get(column)}
            )
        ).enter().append("td").text((d)=> 
            for column in @columns
                if d.column == column
                    return d.val
        )
    $("#" + @tableId).dataTable({
        "bScrollInfinite" : true,
        "bScrollCollapse" : true,
        "sScrollY" : "80%",
        "sScrollX" : "80%",
        "bFilter" : false,
        "bInfo" : false

    })
```

How do I make it so that the table re-renders and shows only the rows that meet the condition of filter func?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use D3's [filter function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) to filter a selection. Then you can operate as usual on the filtered selection, e.g. remove it. So your code would look something like this (assuming that your filter function returns true for the elements you want to keep).

```
@rows.filter((d) -> !@filterFunc(toFilter, d))
     .remove()
```

Alternatively, you can filter your data before passing it to `.data()` and then operate on the selections.

```
@rows = @tbody.selectAll("tr")
          .data(@collection.models.filter((d) -> !@filterFunc(toFilter, d)), (d) -> d)
@rows.exit().remove()
@rows.enter().append("tr")...
```

I've added a second argument to the `.data()` function here to tell D3 to match data items by their value rather than their index.

Comment: so I figured that out - the problem now is that when I call exit() I get a no method error, which is weird...

Comment: nvm, I got around that - I'm now wondering how to keep the original rows? Like when I hit backspace, the search should re-do, with the above code the @rows seems to have become the filtered data

Comment: In that case it would be easier to filter your data, then pass it to `.data()` and operate on the appropriate selections. What I posted doesn't bind new data to the rows, so there is no `.exit()` selection.

Comment: mind posting code? I can't visualize it- so have a data for the removal and one for re-rendering the stuff that needs to be displayed after changing the filter? if you suggested @rows.filter(stuff).data().enter(), I'm getting that enter is not a function as an error